# Custom Progress Bar not working on some devices

Tags: android, android-progressbar, nine-patch, xml-drawable

## EDIT:

I have created a progress bar that uses only nine-patch drawables and another that depends on clip drawables as I have posted below,I have posted both the projects on `github`.Can someone with a Sony device test the projects and tell me which one works for them(the device where it was not working was an `Xperia M`).I have posted links in comments,or you could tell me where I can test online for free.

This code works on my Galaxy Nexus but it does not seem to work on certain devices...
I have created a custom progress bar using the following xml file:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <!-- Background is a rectangle with a solid black fill -->

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#000000"/>  
            <stroke android:width="4dp"
                        android:color="#ffffff"/>
            
        </shape>
    </item>
    
    <!-- The secondary progress,a gradient with a stroke and a padding -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
                <gradient 
                    android:startColor="#6c006d"
                    android:centerColor="#e100e0"
                    android:endColor="#ff28ff"
                    android:angle="0"
                    android:type="linear"
                    />
                 <stroke android:width="4dp"
                        android:color="#ffffff"/>
                
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
    
    <item android:id="@+id/progress">
   <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
        <stroke android:width="4dp"
                    android:color="#ffffff"/>
    <scale android:scaleWidth="100%"
           android:drawable="@drawable/untitled_1"/></shape>        
       </item>
    
      </layer-list>
```

This is the XML I used to define the ProgressBar in XML:

```
 <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progressbar_update"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="100"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progressbar"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            />
```

Two of my friends using Sony smartphones reported problems with the app not showing the progress or throwing an error when the progressbar is supposed to load.I update the progressbar using an AsyncTask within a fragment that retains it's instance like this:

```
 @Override
public void onProgressUpdate(Bitmap bitmap,int progress) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int size = (int) ( bitmap .getHeight() * (1024.0 / bitmap .getWidth()) );
    Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap , 1024, size, true);
    img_currentOp.setImageBitmap(scaled);
    updatebar.setProgress(progress);
}
```

The pattern for using this combination was suggested [here](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html)

This is the image I used for creating the progress bar:[image: Image for displaying progress]

Comment: Using clip-drawables,mostly,the code in the question https://github.com/vamsiampolu/CustomProgressBar

Comment: Using nine-patch drawables https://github.com/vamsiampolu/NinePatchProgress

Answer (score 0):

I guess the radius you have mentioned in the corner tag wont be working..!

```
<corners android:radius="8dp"/>
```

me too faced problems in device with version 2.X.X;

**Use NinePatch images instead of the drawable[if possible]**

Comment: I have tried converting the untitled_1 image to a nine patch...it did not work on the device,should I use three 9 patch images instead...what should I use as corners tag.